# overriding value and creating extra value while using foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

accepting serialized data array from javaScript, and i want to work with each array value of serialized data. but when data is updated its overriding name field and creating extra array with only name field.

```
['checked_dns=0&name=localhost.vias.jfkl.&domain=via…12520&type=A&record=*.*.*.*&ttl_sel=14400', 'checked_dns=2&name=ns1.vias.jfkl.&domain=vias.jfkl…12369&type=A&record=*.*.*.*ttl_sel=14400', 'checked_dns=3&name=ns2.vias.jfkl.&domain=vias.jfkl…15000&type=A&record=*.*.*.*&ttl_sel=14400']
```

This Serialized array i am receiving.

```
$data_arr = $_POST['arr'];
    foreach($data_arr as $value){
        $single_arr = [];
        $single_arr = explode("&",$value);
        foreach($single_arr as $val){
            $single = explode("=",$val);
            $final_arr[$single[0]] = $single[1];

            
            // // Just Check
            $name = $final_arr['name'];
            $point = $final_arr['edit_record'];
            $ttl = $final_arr['ttl_sel'];
            $type = $final_arr['type'];
            $address = $final_arr['record'];
                            
            // Checking done now edit record        
            $check = $softpanel->fun_for_update_record($point, $name, $ttl, $type, $address);

        }
        
    }
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Your inner `for` loop should only be populating the final array. Once that is done, outside of that loop, but still inside the first one, you can use it. This code shows but, but has some invalid keys which I’ll leave to you to fix: https://3v4l.org/ZumFu

Comment: i want to update my record for all array values...